# CSS Dropdown Issues

Tags: css, menu, drop-down-menu

I am a .NET / Java guy and have to do some website stuff. Complete beginner with CSS etc. I've been working with a template and had to convert the menu to a drop down and have been having loads of difficulty.

I've uploaded the current iteration and it can be found here with the barebones menu and css pages:

http://www.nitricburnstudios.com/tmp/cssproblems/features.html

The menu items are overlapping with one another.

Thanks for any help! SUPER appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it depends on 1) if you just want to get something working, or 2) you insist oin doing it yourself and understanding it.

if 1) I swear by http://wonderwebware.com/css-menu/ a CSS menu generator (you don't need to use it, just study it's output)

if 2) the fist thing you need to do is to lean about the W3C's validation services. I ran your dropdown.css through the [CSS validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input) and it had 1 error, which might be causing your problem "Property behavior doesn't exist : url(csshover.htc) url(csshover.htc)"

Styles.css had 11 warnings "Same colors for color and background-color in two contexts", which might explain why I couldn't see any text on the menus :-)

The good news is that the HTML validator says that your HTML is ok.

If you want to study CSS, I can recommend some great sites

Comment: Wasn't aware of either of those tools. The CSS generator is really great. I don't really have the time to invest into learning CSS right now and down the line will have some money to pay a proper web guy so perfect for what I need right now. Thanks!

Comment: No problems. The W3C is the official standards body, so their validators ought to be correct; anything validated there *should* display correctly in moist browsers (*cough* MSIE *cough*). By all means use off the shelf stuff (but check the license since you are commercial; stay away from GPL, although LGPL is ok, as are Apache, MIT, etc if in doubt, ask a lawyer)  I recommend using PHP, not HTML, as you will probably want some logic sooner or later.   If you do go for PHP, why not visit http://www.cmsmatrix.org/ and use something from there. You might be amazed by what Drupal, etc offers you

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is possible for your project, but there are lots of canned [solutions](http://www.google.com/search?num=100&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=YLD&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=css+dropdown+menu&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) to [this](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/resources/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/) that should prevent you from reinventing the wheel.

Comment: +1 Also, most of the browser inconsistencies are worked out with the canned solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple vertical example that may get you started:

HTML

```
  <div id='dropper'>
    <div>Foo</div>
    <div>Bar</div>
    <div>Bas</div>
    <div>Snork</div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
#dropper { overflow: hidden; height:25px; line-height:25px }
#dropper:hover { height:100px }
```